# Tagged dataset with photos for race detection

Tags: dataset, data, image-classification, image-recognition

Looking for the tagged dataset, because I would like to identify race by photo. I tried using the UTKFace dataset from Kaggle, but it outputs hispanic and Arab people on images as `other`. My customer would like those ones as separate categories. Do you have any datasets like that? Because UTKFace has only 4 tags - `black`, `white`, `indian`, `other`.

Comment: This would be a question for https://opendata.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this should go to open data SE https://opendata.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @Peter sorry, I didn't know that there is a separate section for data questions. I can delete the question myself if you want.

Comment: That‘s okay. Just post it there to have a good chance of getting good feedback...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, I believe I found one:

https://github.com/dchen236/FairFace